# Point on unit circle such that $|(z-a_1)\cdots(z-a_n)|=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

> Let $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ be points on the unit circle. Let $P(z)=(z-a_1)\cdots(z-a_n)$. Prove that there exists a point $b$ on the unit circle such that $|P(b)|=1$.

My solution: $|P(0)|=1$, and $P$ is holomorphic in $|z|\leq 1$. By the maximum principle, there exists $z$ on the unit circle such that $|P(z)|>1$. But $P(a_1)=0$. By intermediate value theorem, there exists $b$ on the unit circle such that $|P(b)|=1$.

Question: Is there a way to avoid the maximum principle?

Comment: Intermediate value theorem works for functions from connected (topological) spaces to ordered (topological) spaces. However, $P : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $, Yes $\mathbb{C} $ is connected but $\mathbb{C} $ is not an ordered space.

Comment: I think you can avoid using IMVT , and just using the maximum modulus principle is sufficient.

Comment: Modulus of $P$ is a function from the unit circle _to_ $\mathbb{R},$ so there is no problem using the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @IgorRivin Thank you for correcting my comment

Comment: @BenjaminDickman Since $P$ is not constant, a point with $\lvert P(z)\rvert > 1$ on the unit circle is guaranteed by the maximum principle.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use Rouché's theorem to avoid the maximum principle ;)

Suppose there were no $b$ on the unit circle with $\lvert P(b)\rvert = 1$. Since $P$ has zeros on the unit circle, we would then have $\lvert P(z)\rvert < 1$ for all $z \in \mathbb{S}$.

Consider $f(z) = (-1)^n \prod\limits_{k=1}^n a_k$ and $g(z) = f(z) - P(z)$. Since

$$\lvert f(z) - g(z)\rvert = \lvert P(z)\rvert < 1 = \lvert f(z)\rvert$$

on $\mathbb{S}$, Rouché's theorem asserts that $f$ and $g$ have the same number of zeros in the unit disk. But $f$ is constant and nonzero, and $g(0) = f(0) - P(0) = 0$, contradiction.

Earnestly: the maximum principle provides a quick and direct natural proof, use it.